# what transition to have between two screens when there is where minor change in content?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, microinteractions

I have a series of files that the user can look into.
The user can open any file and view the file, and the user can navigate using arrows to view the next file. The problem I am facing is where there is a very minor change in the content when the user navigates to another file. What transitions should I use between these screens? How do I tell the users that they are now viewing the next file?

pfa attached images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here, as I understand it, is "Feedback".

The goal is to make the user understand what is hapenning et what will change.

For this, I would recommand to try out some micro-interactions that'll help the user to understand what's hapening. (You don't want him to feel lost)

This can be for example :
- Adding a layer of information (like the place of the file in the folder somewhere on the screen or "adding" a window like Google Analytics does)
- Adding a layer of animation (like a "Switch", as you can find on Tinder for example)

But more importantly, you should test it. Since this is some tweaking really precise on the UX/UI, you should check multiple solutions and try to find the most appropriate one.

I've encountered something similar with one of my projects where we tested A LOT. Of course it was in a VR environment so we had the opportunity to add visual AND audio feedback to be sure that users understand what's hapenning. In your case, you should play with visual feedback as much as you can!

Hope this will help,
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As a UX/UI designer, here are some graphic design ideas that may result in what you wish for. But these ideas are without researching the current UX patterns:

1. Add a subhead to the File Name (i.e. 1 of 5)
2. Alternate background colors as clicking NEXT (from white to light grey and repeat this alternating pattern)
3. Next and Previous buttons trigger a transition animation (carousel slider)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a progress indicator even if the loading is instantaneous. A non-blocking 300ms animation should work just fine.